# What does it mean to be SET distance/similarity metric?

Tags: metric-spaces

I was looking at Tverski contrast distance :

d(x,y) = a * f(x intersect y) - b * f(x-y) - c * f(y-x)

in binary :

d(x,y) = a * count(x&y) - b * count(x&~y) - c * count(~x&y)

It is said that it is SET DISTANCE metric !!

How to understand this ? Beside the obvious, what does it mean to be a SET metric.
For distance like Euclidean and Hamming it is easier to visualize it as distance between two points in N-dimentional space, not so for a SET !

Comment: A set metric is a distance whose inputs are two sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tversky_index

Comment: Hmm, this does not appear to be a metric unless $a=0$ -- otherwise $d(\{p\},\{p\})$ fails to vanish. (Similarly, $b$ and $c$ had better be equal and negative).